# Import Functionality From Other Addons?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I was wondering if there was an elegant way to import functionality from other installed add-ons. In particular, I wish to import classes these add-ons, and use them in my own code. It is not necessary to actually enable/register these add-ons.

Comment: Do you have any specific case(s) in mind?   Can for instance `from io_scene_3ds import Import3DS` check if it's registered `Import3DS.is_registered` and if not register it in your code (even change `Import3DS.bl_idname`) with `bpy.utils.register_class(Import3DS)`.  Rather than classes it may be "more elegant" to `from io_scene_3ds.import_3ds import load_3ds` and use this directly to import. (untested)

Comment: @batFINGER All I needed to know was that you can simply do `from add_dir_name import thingy`. Thanks :)